# @Html.Partial em WebForm

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Existe como no WebForm utilizar vários  @Html.Partial ? exemplo o menu ser uma master page, o topo outra master page, o rodapé outra master page?

sei que existe a NestedMasterPage porém se o menu não for criado desde o começo,
Exemplo já tenho uma masterpage chamada site e agora quero que essa chame uma masterpage que será só o menu.

como fazer? melhor fazer com javascript `.onload` ou tem como fazer esse include?

Comment: Não... não misture tecnologias. já tem a técnica ideal em WebForms para isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

descobri.
Web **Form User Control**, assim você pode inserir em uma masterpage já existente um novo html